# Exclude a Single file from test coverage

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs

Is it possible to tell jest to exclude a specific **File** from the test coverage report? I am not looking for `.skip` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!src/file.ext" // <-- use the negation operator to exclude files or paths
    ]
  }
```